# How do I share a session across two domains with Cake's database session handling?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, single-sign-on

I am SO close to an elegant cross-domain session-sharing solution (which I will happily post to the CakePHP community), but I need one last nudge to complete it.

Cake's native DB-backed session handling seems quite lacking, but I hate to hack on top of it.  It does not appear to support passing an active session ID (sid) from Server A (that exists in the database) and then starting a new session on Server B with that ID (and data intact).

Here's where I got:

I set Security = Low, and I test single-server logging in, etc to ensure sessions are behaving normally.  Check.

I successfully pass the sid string from Server A to Server B.  Now on Server B...

I run CakeSession::id($sid_from_server_a).

I parse out the data field in the sessions DB table and deposit them into the active session through $this->Session->write('blah','value').

I re-read the session to make sure it "took".

But when I navigate to a new page, the active sid simply snaps back to a totally different sid that stays the same with other page loads (even if I refresh the page that re-establishes the sid from Server A).

Is this a cookie problem?

I'm not sure what left to do but bypass the whole Cake paradigm.  It seems that Cake developers did not design the session handling to help with re-establishing existing sessions around multiple domains.  I thought that was one of the main benefits of the DB session handler.

Comment: Both.  Each server is in a different domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do on Server B was properly re-initialize the session.  Pretty basic:

```
session_write_close(); // close any session that has already initialized
CakeSession::id($sid_from_server_a); // or: session_id($sid_from_server_a);
session_start();
```

I assumed before that all I needed was that second line, that setting the new sid in the CakeSession wrapper would prompt the session to start.  But it is more akin to running session_id($some_sid) the old PHP way... you can do this to set up the session before actually starting it.

In general I had some vague notion that CakePHP would automagically start the session when I wanted, but really scanning the CakeSession class shows it doesn't do much -- it is a thinly veiled convenience wrapper for native PHP session handling.

I didn't even have to parse out the pseudo-serialized session data in the sessions DB table and all that jazz -- totally unnecessary.  The code above does the trick: cross-domain session sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a cookie problem, you'll need a cookie to store the session information that you want to  return to. As far as I know, there is no other way to recall that type of session information. I'm not sure what you're project would require you to save, but without some information the server has no choice but to create a new session when it crosses domains. Good luck.